# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in sqlite (android)

Tags: android, sqlite

i have create a table in sqlite that giving me **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**
here is code :

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+scoreboardTable+" ("+scoreboard_id+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"+" FOREIGN KEY ( "+player_fk+ ") REFERENCES "+playerTable+" ("+playerid+ "), "
        +"FOREIGN KEY ( "+ Template_fk+ ") REFERENCES " +TemplateTable+" ("+ templateid+ "),"+ total_flick+"int"+surprise_success+"varchar"+surprise_failure+"varchar)");
    }
```

and

```
public void Insert_scoreboard(String[] str) 
    {
        try
        {
        SQLiteDatabase DB= this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

        cv.put("scoreboard_id", str[0]);
        cv.put("player_fk", str[1]);
        cv.put("Template_fk", str[2]);
        cv.put("total_flick", str[3]);
        cv.put("surprise_success", str[4]);
        cv.put("surprise_failure", str[5]);


        DB.insert( scoreboardTable , "scoreboard", cv);
        DB.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.toString();
        }
```

where im doing wrong .

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but another possibility for receiving this is if you're using a PreparedStatement and you've put single quotes around your `?` parameters. It will treat them as a string literal and ignore your parameter. Question-mark parameter should not be quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have error in `Create Table Syntax` ( you forgot comma **,** at some places ) update your code with following code,

```
db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + scoreboardTable + " (" + scoreboard_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," + " FOREIGN KEY ( "+player_fk+ ") REFERENCES " + playerTable + " (" + playerid + "), " + "FOREIGN KEY ( " + Template_fk + ") REFERENCES " + TemplateTable + " (" + templateid + ")," + total_flick + "int, " + surprise_success + "varchar, " + surprise_failure + "varchar)" );
    }
```